# Curl a JSON with json_decode

Tags: json, sql-server, curl

I need insert into SQL Server table a result from curl ->json
The field is a HTML string and if I read from web is

```html
<ul>
    <li><strong>Élégance Classique</strong> : Rehaussez votre garde-robe avec cette pièce essentielle qui incarne sans effort l'élégance classique. Le col boutonné ajoute une touche de sophistication, en faisant un choix polyvalent pour toute occasion.</li>
( ul, li ecc)
```

in the table I have

```
\n\n\u003cul\u003e\n\t\u003cli\u003e\u003cstrong\u003eÉlégance Classique\u003c\/strong\u003e : Rehaussez votre garde-robe avec cette pièce essentielle qui incarne sans effort l'élégance classique. Le col boutonné ajoute une touche de sophistication, en faisant un choix polyvalent pour toute occasion.
```

trasform < ul> to \u003cul

Is possible in to convert it? I need a HTML code not other.

Comment: Have you tried consuming your "JSON" (it's not quite JSON, but easily made to be) *as JSON*? Why didn't that work?

Comment: How was the text inserted? How did *the application code* convert it? StackOverflow uses SQL Server itself, so this very question proves that SQL Server has no problem with HTML, JSON or Unicode.

Comment: How is the text *displayed* ? Are you sure you aren't confusing a debugger's watch view or program's verbose output for the actual content? A debugger would show `\n` and `\t` if the text contained newlines and tabs instead of the rendered string

Comment: I see the result and is this '\n\n\u003cul\u003e\n\t\u003cli\u003e\u003cstrong\u003e+ël+®gance Classique\u003c\/strong\u003e : Rehaussez votre garde-robe ', or I create a sql (replace) or I try to find a native resolution

Comment: Maybe store it as `xml` type assuming it's valid XHTML. I don't get how JSON is relevant here

Comment: Do you just want `STRING_ESCAPE(YourValue, 'json')` or something?